# Getting the max value of attributes from a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes, max

I have this list of objects which have a x and a y parameter (and some other stuff).

```
path.nodes = (
    <GSNode x=535.0 y=0.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=634.0 y=0.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=377.0 y=706.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=279.0 y=706.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=10.0 y=0.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=110.0 y=0.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=189.0 y=216.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>,
    <GSNode x=458.0 y=216.0 GSLINE GSSHARP>
)
```

I need to have the max y of this list. Though, I tried this:

```
print(max(path.nodes, key=y))
```

And I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

I am kinda new to Python and the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) give me no clue. I think I am doing wrong with the keyword because if iterate through nodes like this:

```
for node in path.nodes:
    print(node.y)
```

I'll get the values of y.
Could somebody provide me an explanation?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To get just the maximum value and not the entire object you can use a generator expression:

```
print(max(node.y for node in path.nodes))
```

Comment: I would've chosen the `key=lambda x: x.y` way, just like the others. But **this** is what you really can call *pythonic*! +1

Comment: This is the most _pythonic_ expression ever!

Answer (score 40):

There is an important difference for when to use the "Pythonic" style #1 versus lambda style #2:

```
max(node.y for node in path.nodes)  # (style #1)
```

versus

```
max(path.nodes, key=lambda item: item.y)  # (style #2)
```

If you look carefully you can see that style #1 returns the maximum value for the attribute `y` while style #2 returns the `node` that has maximum attribute `y`. These two are not the same and code usage is important in case you want to iterate over the attribute values or iterate over the objects that holds that attribute.

Example:

```
class node():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = self.x + 10

node_lst = [node(1), node(2), node(3), node(4), node(5)]
print([(e.x,e.y) for e in node_lst])

>>> [(1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14), (5, 15)]
```

Now:

```
maxy = max(node.y for node in node_lst)
print(maxy)
>>> 15

max_node = max(node_lst, key=lambda node: node.y)
print(max_node.y)
>>> 15
```

Answer (score 35):

There's a built-in to help with this case.

```
import operator

print(max(path.nodes, key=operator.attrgetter('y')))
```

Alternatively:

```
print(max(path.nodes, key=lambda item: item.y))
```

Edit: But Mark Byers' answer is most Pythonic.

```
print(max(node.y for node in path.nodes))
```

Comment: In my case the most pythonic way is what I was looking for. But in the  other examples is there an advantage of the attrgetter() over the lambda style?

Comment: The `lambda` approach is what I like the most. It connects nicely with `C#` and `JavaScript`.

Comment: Mark Byers' answer is not equivalent to your first two snippets. His answer returns the maximum value of the attribute y, not the node associated with this value.

Comment: @PDXIII: Two advantages: 1) `lambda` can do anything, so maintainers have to look at it more closely (`lambda item: -item.y` is easily overlooked; `attrgetter` does exactly one thing so maintainers who know of it can speed past it (this is a general advantage of using `operator` and `functools` stuff over `lambda`). 2) In theory, the `attrgetter` can be more efficient (especially if it's reading multiple attributes); in the CPython reference interpreter, it's implemented at the C layer, so in most cases, the bytecode interpreter will not be invoked at all per item.

Answer (score 5):

```
from operator import attrgetter
print(max(path.nodes, key=attrgetter("y")))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to implement the `__gt__` comparison operator for an object, and than use `max` without a key function:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.y > other.y
```

and than something like:

```
ls = [node(3), node(5), node(11), node(0)]
print(max(ls).y)
```

is supposed to output *11*.

Answer (score 0):

`y` isn't defined as a variable; it's an attribute of individual `GSNode` objects; you can't use it as a name on its own.

To access the individual attributes you can use something like `key=lambda x: x.y` or `attrgetter()` from the `operator` module.

Answer (score 0):

*If `y` is a property attribute* then you don't even need to import `operator.attrgetter`. You can use [`fget`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) method instead:

```
my_node = max(path.nodes, key=Node.y.fget)
```

This will return the `Node` instance from where to get the max `y` value is just `my_node.y`

Answer (score 0):

they already answered you, but if you want to get the object who has the max value:

```
max_val_object = lambda x: max(ob.value for ob in x)
```